# CSS/images not being loaded in Jekyll blog

Tags: ruby, blogs, jekyll, webrick

I am new to Jekyll and just trying to start a Jekyll Theme [example](http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/minimal-mistakes/). I tried a few other themes too and all of them only load up at port 4000 with basic text and no images/styling.

- Fork the project.
- Clone the repo in my local machine
- bundle install
- jekyll serve

The server starts and I can look at the page but it is very ugly without the styling.

I know I can change the variables and configurations but I just wanted to run this as it is first. I can see all the images and in the images folder but why is this not being loaded on the blog?

I am new to Jekyll so please let me know if there is something wrong with this. `Jekyll serve` is the correct way to start the server right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you updated the URL in _config.yml? This is used to build the links to the CSS and scripts.

When working locally you should comment it out. If you haven't already open _config.yml and change

```
url:              http://your-site.com
```

to

```
#url:              http://your-site.com
```

When you publish to a live site uncomment the line and update the url.

Comment: Excellent. Just tried it out. That was exactly the problem. I did not know that the url was used to build the links. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the `baseurl: "/"` instead of `""` which broke my paths. So that's worth checking. The current answer lead me in the right direction to check my `_config.yml` but `url:` was not the problem.